# Referencing inside of loops R

Tags: r, arrays, string, for-loop

So i'm trying to create some different plots, based on parameters ABS, ATC and ATR and split into two groups, managers and not managers.

```
for (i in c(1:length(type_of_worker))){
  for (j in c(1:length(remuneration))){
    assign(paste0(remuneration[j],type_of_worker[i],"_plot"),
           ggplot()+
            geom_point(data=get(paste0(type_of_worker[i],"_data")),mapping=aes(y=compensationGradeIntegers, x=paste0(type_of_worker[i],"_data$",remuneration[j])),color="#A8CAE5",size=1)+
            theme_classic()
    )
  }
}
```

The problem seems to be when I try to assign x. I would like it to run trough ABS, ATC and ATR but it just reads it as a string puts all the information into 1 horizontal line when plotting. Data sets are called:
`Workers_data` and `Managers_data`

Comment: Providing some mock data with the shape of what you have would be helpful. It's very hard to figure out the output you want if we have no idea on the input.

Comment: It has columns with Worker(String),IPE(Integer),ABS(Double),ATC(Double),ATR(Double). The main problem seems to be with the mapping of the first axis(ABS/ATC/ATR):
```x=paste0(type_of_worker[i],"_data$",remuneration[j]))```